# Ember: working with http-mock and improper JSON

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to work with http-mock feature of Ember-cli. My plan is not input **some improper JSON(without root model, no Ids, embedded model instead of side loaded model etc etc)** . Since i am new to this i first tried setting up a mock server with proper data and it was successful. Below is the relevant code.

adapters/post.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api',
});
```

pods/post/route.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});
```

models/post.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default  DS.Model.extend({
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
 comments: DS.hasMany('comments')
});
```

server/mocks/posts.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var postsRouter = express.Router();

  postsRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send({
      "posts" : [{
         'id': 1,
         'author': 'Brian',
         'title': 'Ember JS',
         'body': 'JS framework for creating ambitious web applications',
         'comments': [11,12]
       }]
    });
  });

  app.use('/api/posts', postsRouter);
};
```

This this point everything works fine. The above mock server data relates to the below JSON from an API call

```
{
    "posts" : [{
        'id': 1,
        'author': 'Brian',
        'title': 'Ember JS',
        'body': 'JS framework for creating ambitious web applications',
        'comments': [11,12]
    }]
}
```

How would i write my mock-server code to produce a JSON which looks like this **without root model**?

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'author': 'Brian',
    'title': 'Ember JS',
    'body': 'JS framework for creating ambitious web applications',
    'comments': [11,12]
}
```

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance.

-Anees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured out a way myself and turned out to be quite easy.

server/mocks/posts.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var postsRouter = express.Router();

  postsRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(

      {
        'id': 1,
        'author': 'Brian',
        'title': 'Ember JS',
        'body': 'JS framework for creating ambitious web applications',
        'comments': [{
          'author': 'Jimmy',
          'body': 'Its cool',
        },
        {
          'author': 'Jake',
          'body': 'steep learning curve'
        }]
      }

    );
  });

  app.use('/api/posts', postsRouter);
};
```

So basically its as simple as putting your desired JSON inside

```
res.send(


);
```

Thanks